# use menu item title instead of page title in breadcrumbs

Tags: navigation, 7, breadcrumbs

I have been trying to display the menu item title as the trailing item in my breadcrumbs, other than the page title.

At this point, I override the `template_breadcrumb()` function with a custom function. At the end of the string variable, I have put `drupal_get_title()` to append the page title to the breadcrumb trail.

Please find a snippet out of the breadcrumb function below:

```
foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
  $crumbs .= $value;
}
$crumbs .= drupal_get_title();
```

Now, **when available**, I would prefer the linked navigation item title to be displayed as trailing breadcrumb item. If not available, I will display the page title.

How can I check if this page is attached to a menu item, and retrieve the title, in order to display it as a breadcrumb item ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at this module: http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb
It sounds perfect for your needs.

Some details from the module's project page:

> By default, Drupal 6+ use the Navigation menu for the breadcrumb. This module allows you to use the menu the current page belongs to for the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) module.
In the configuration (Admin > Structure > Crumbs), look for

```
menu.link_title.*
menu.link_title.devel      - Development
menu.link_title.main-menu  - Main menu
menu.link_title.management - Management
menu.link_title.navigation - Navigation
menu.link_title.user-menu  - User menu
```

This is already enabled by default.
To disable it for specific menus, move the respective line into the "disabled" section.